# Dynamic_sidebar inside wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, sidebar, walker

I have Menu created by wp_nav_menu. 
Inside it, I want to set dynamic_sidebar but wp_nav_menu instead of displaying the content, throws 1.

Have everyone some tips for display sidebar inside wp_nav_menu? 
I have to add dynamic_sidebar inside menu it's important.

Inside walker I placed the code:

```
$item_output .= '
    <div class="recipes__dropdown">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="dropdown__content">
                <div class="row">' . dynamic_sidebar( 'recipes-dropdown' ) . '</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
```

Have you any suggestions how include dynamic sidebar inside wp_nav_menu?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add extra items in menu like

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if ($args->theme_location == '[YOUR-MENU-LOCATION]') {
        $items .= '--YOUR EXTRA STUFF HERE--';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that `dynamic_sidebar` does `echo` and we need to get its content not `echo` it inside `wp_nav_menu`.
Try to do like this:

```
ob_start();
$sidebar = dynamic_sidebar( 'recipes-dropdown' );
$sidebar = ob_get_contents();
$item_output .= $sidebar;
ob_end_clean();
```

This helped me to make it work.